# String List not de-serializing, whereas custom List is

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a Scene object that contains a list of strings, the names of image files used in the scene. I am serializing and de-serializing this using Json.NET. I need this list to be created before my list of GameObjects, which look for their texture in the list of file names.

```
class Scene : Nameable
{
    List<String> sceneContent = new List<string>();
    List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    public Scene(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public List<String> SceneContent
    {
        get { return sceneContent; }
        set { sceneContent = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public List<GameObject> GameObjects
    {
        get { return gameObjects; }
        set { gameObjects = value; }
    }

    public void CreateNullBodys(World world)
    {
        foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
        {
            BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, obj.Width, obj.Height, 1f, obj.Position, obj.Name);
            obj.Body.BodyType = obj.Type;
            obj.Body.CollisionCategories = Category.All;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see i have tried adding JsonProperty Order to this class in a hope to get it do serialize them first. However this does not seem to be working, even after the de-serialization is finished, this list is not filled. The output of my serialization can be found here: http://pastebin.com/A5qjNhhV. If anyone has any ideas as to why this list is not getting de-serialized whereas the list of GameObjects is, please help me to understand whats happening!

Edit: Serialization code:

```
public Scene LoadScene(String sceneName)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/game/scenes/" + sceneName + ".scene");
        String jsonScene = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Scene scene = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Scene>(jsonScene);
        reader.Close();
        return scene;
    }

    public void SaveScene(Scene scene)
    {
        String jsonScene = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scene, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(jsonScene);
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/game/scenes/" + scene.Name + ".scene");
        file.Write(jsonScene);
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to serialize the object?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that, it's in now.

Comment: Lex, your deserializer works just fine. I guess, somewhere in your code, the SceneContent list is being erased and you falsely assume that the Json.NET did not deserialize it (but it does). Or, do you somewhere in your code set custom deserialzation settings, contracts or converters affecting List<string> deserialization?

Comment: I'm not using any custom settings anywhere. The only piece of code that ever touches that list is where i iterate through them in order to get the file names.

Comment: I tested your code with your Json example from pastebin and it worked properly. Which Json.NET version are you using and which .NET framework version is your project targetting?

Comment: Regarding code touching the list, can you verify by making the `sceneContent` private and setting a breakpoint on the getter of the `SceneContent` property?

Comment: @elgonzo Json.NET 6.0.3, .NET 4. I tried making it private. Putting the break-point specifically on the getter revealed that it is initially set correctly, where i was debugging the code before was before it is set (On creation of gameObjects). Which leads me back to my original guess that the object creation is happening before the string list is initialized. Which should not happen per the ordering.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53911/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-lex-webb)

Answer (score 0):

I have not resolved the issue regarding de-serialization ordering. But i have resolved this specific issue by re-iterating through each of my game objects and updating all the values not set in the initial constructor because of the empty list.

It is also worth noting that the list is indeed being populated, but only after the list of game objects has been.